# Android gradle build error - algorithm: No such file or directory. (In opencv)

Tags: android, c, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to run a sample program with opencv for image acquisition. But I got the build error.

```
D:\Work\Code\Practice\Android\CornerDetector\app\src\main\jni\opencv2\core\base.hpp
Error:(53, 21) algorithm: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include D:\Work\Code\Addons\ZAndroid\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

    LOCAL_MODULE := mCameraSlider

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/driver_android_slider.c    \
                       src/driver_android_camera.cpp  \
                       src/driver_android_display.cpp \
                       src/main.c                     \
                       src/mCameraSlider.c            \
                       src/corner/myCorners.c         \

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)\src\include \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)\src\corner  \


    LOCAL_LDLIBS  +=  -llog -ldl
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM :=android-9
```

Some drivers for android camera is using opencv2/core/core.hpp, therefore opencv2 directory is place under jni.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

extern JavaVM *cachedJvm;
extern jobject cachedActivityObj;
extern jclass cachedMainActivityCls;

typedef struct _CameraContext
{
    jmethodID CameraGetInputBufferID;
    jmethodID InitCameraID;    

    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Location;

    cv::Mat Temp;
    cv::Mat Repo;
} CameraContext;
```

When doing ndk build getting this:
[image]

I think I am doing something wrong in using opencv, maybe android.mk but not sure.
Kindly help.

**UPDATE:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mohantysolutions.cornerdetector"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

Comment: Show me you Gradle Build file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was I missed the configuration in gradle to include jni srcDir.
Once I added the below code to gradle, everything works fine.

```
sourceSets.main{
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

I hope this may prove helpful to someone.

Comment: This solved the problem with building it. But the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the Gradle Build file, so I am guessing the solution based on the error message you provided.

Open Cv does not work properly on newer Android SDKs because of the newer Camera API added. And until now Open CV is not updated for usage with newer SDKs.

So if you compiling your APP with android SDK version 23, then you have that problem.

Try to choose any SDKs that use the older Camera API not the new one.

Comment: You are right, build gradle is targeting sdk version 23, I can change to lower sdk and gives you the feedback.

Comment: Okay, if you have errors after changing, download the older sdks from SDK Manager and then create a new application project and then import the Open CV Libraries into your app

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I get the supported version of my OpenCV build? My projects did require android sdk 25...